# $A_n$ is the commutator subgroup of $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $K$ be the commutator subgroup of $S_n$ and $t$ a transposition of $S_n$. Then $\langle t\rangle K$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$ since $S_n/K$ is abelian.

I don't get it. How can I use the fact that $S_n/K$ is abelian to prove the $\langle t\rangle K$ is normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g\in S_n$ and $x\in\langle t\rangle K$. We have to prove that $gxg^{-1}\in\langle t\rangle K$.

By definition we can write $x=t^ik$ for some $k\in K$. Since $S_n/K$ is abelian we have $gt^iK=t^igK$. So there is some $k_1\in K$ such that $gt^ik=t^igk_1$. And then:

$gxg^{-1}=gt^ikg^{-1}=t^i(gk_1g^{-1})\in \langle t\rangle K$

We used the fact that $gk_1g^{-1}\in K$. (which is true because $K$ is normal in $S_n$)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. This was from Kurtzweil and Stellmacher, The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction. I think the authors here write for super intelligent people.